# Avoid Widget and Frame Overlapping in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

So i created a new Widget and i'm trying to put it to the right of the frame i created but pyqt is overlapping them instead the widget on it's own works fine. I also tried QHboxLayout and QVBoxLayout but both of them didn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QAction, QApplication, QDesktopWidget,
                             QDialog, QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QWidget,QListWidget,QScrollBar,QListWidgetItem)
class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1280,720)
        tempWidget=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tempWidget)
        tempFrame=QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.palette=tempFrame.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        tempFrame.setPalette(self.palette)
        tempFrame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        box=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        box.addWidget(tempFrame,0,0,1,3)
        box.addWidget(someWidget(),0,1,1,1)
        tempWidget.setLayout(box)
        self.show()
class someWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ribbon = QListWidget()
        self.chat = QTextEdit()
        scroll_bar = QScrollBar()
        scroll_bar.setStyleSheet("background : lightgrey;")
        self.ribbon.setVerticalScrollBar(scroll_bar)
        self.chat.setFixedHeight(
            int((self.chat.fontMetrics().lineSpacing() * 3) +
            (self.chat.document().documentMargin() * 2) +
            (self.chat.frameWidth() * 2) - 1)
            )
        sendBtn = QPushButton('Send')
        sendBtn.clicked.connect(self.Something)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(3)
        grid.addWidget(self.ribbon, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.chat, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(sendBtn, 1, 2)
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)
    def Something(self):
        self.ribbon.addItem(QListWidgetItem(self.chat.toPlainText()));self.chat.setText('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Some unrelated but still important suggestions: 1. class and constant names should always be capitalized, while functions and variables should always start with a lowercase letter; 2. there should always be a blank line between functions and two to separate classes; 3. always put spaces around the equal symbol used for assignment; 4. don't use the semicolon to separate functions. Don't underestimate all these aspects, as they are *very* important for readability (which is essential). You can read more in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Yeah i should've wrote the code a little more readable, but this was just an temporary example i created in hurry. But i get it i should've.

Comment: Questions shouldn't be created in a hurry, especially their examples :-)

Answer (score 0):

The missing trick here is that the frame by default will consume very little space until you fill it with other widgets. If you do this layout in Designer, you can see that your frame is on the form, but doesn't take up much space. To get around this, you have two options:

1. Put more widgets in your frame and complete its layout
2. Change the QSizePolicy of the QFrame to Expanding. You'll want to add QSizePolicy to the `from PyQt5.QtWidgets` line.

Here is the code for the second option.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QAction, QApplication, QDesktopWidget,
                             QDialog, QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QWidget,
                             QSizePolicy, QListWidget,QScrollBar,QListWidgetItem)
class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1280,720)
        tempWidget=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tempWidget)
        tempFrame=QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.palette=tempFrame.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        tempFrame.setPalette(self.palette)
        tempFrame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        tempFrame.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        box=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        box.addWidget(tempFrame,0,0,1,1)
        box.addWidget(someWidget(),0,1,1,1)
        tempWidget.setLayout(box)
        self.show()
class someWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ribbon = QListWidget()
        self.chat = QTextEdit()
        scroll_bar = QScrollBar()
        scroll_bar.setStyleSheet("background : lightgrey;")
        self.ribbon.setVerticalScrollBar(scroll_bar)
        self.chat.setFixedHeight(
            int((self.chat.fontMetrics().lineSpacing() * 3) +
            (self.chat.document().documentMargin() * 2) +
            (self.chat.frameWidth() * 2) - 1)
            )
        sendBtn = QPushButton('Send')
        sendBtn.clicked.connect(self.Something)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(3)
        grid.addWidget(self.ribbon, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.chat, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(sendBtn, 1, 2)
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)
    def Something(self):
        self.ribbon.addItem(QListWidgetItem(self.chat.toPlainText()));self.chat.setText('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which gives

[image]

As a final note, I changed the column span of the tempFrame to 1. If you really want a column span of 3, I think you need to place the someWidget into column 3.

Comment: Thank you though i did found a fix for this.
I added column strech in the gridLayout and i change the column span to 6 instead of 3 in someWidget. This is the change and i'll put a complete version also in answers.
```py
box.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
box.addWidget(tempFrame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
box.addWidget(CentralWidget(), 0, 1, 1, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone Wondering how i fixed it.I added a columnStrech in box GridLayout and set the widget column span to 6. Don't ask me how it worked cause i won't be able to answer that.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets
import sys
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1280,720)
        tempWidget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tempWidget)
        tempFrame=QtWidgets.QFrame()
        palette=tempWidget.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor(255,255,0))
        tempFrame.setPalette(palette)
        tempFrame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        box=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        box.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
        box.addWidget(tempFrame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        box.addWidget(ChatWidget(), 0, 1, 1, 6)
        tempWidget.setLayout(box)
        self.show()

class ChatWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.chatMessages=QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.inputBox=QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.scrollBar=QtWidgets.QScrollBar()
        self.scrollBar.setStyleSheet('background : lightgrey;')
        self.chatMessages.setVerticalScrollBar(self.scrollBar)
        self.inputBox.setFixedHeight(
            int(
                self.inputBox.fontMetrics().lineSpacing()*3+self.inputBox.document().documentMargin()*2+self.inputBox.frameWidth()*2-1
            )
        )
        self.sendButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Send')
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        grid=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(3)
        grid.addWidget(self.chatMessages, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.inputBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.sendButton, 1, 2)
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
    def onClick(self):
        msg=self.inputBox.toPlainText()
        if not msg:
            return
        self.chatMessages.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(msg))
        self.inputBox.setText('')
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the end Result

[EndResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5jyU.png)